# NatVis display substring of enum

Tags: natvis

We often use prefix for our enums.

It is very verbose to display full name in NatVis.

Is it possible to remove prefix of enum name (AKA return substring of enum name) ?

```cpp
enum FooFormat {
  FooFormat_Foo,
  FooFormat_Bar,
  FooFormat_Baz,
  FooFormat_COUNT
};

struct Bar {
  FooFormat format;
};
```

```
<AutoVisualizer>
  <Type Name="Bar">
    <DisplayString>fmt={format,How-to-get-substring-of-enum-name-?}</DisplayString>
  </Type>
</AutoVisualizer>
```

Answer (score 3):

This does not work:

```xml
<Type Name="FooFormat">
  <DisplayString Condition="this==FooFormat::FooFormat_Foo">Foo</DisplayString>
  <DisplayString Condition="this==FooFormat::FooFormat_Bar">Bar</DisplayString>
  <DisplayString>"bla"</DisplayString>
</Type>
```

But fortunately this works. Of course that is only feasible if your format string does not depend on too many variables, otherwise you might end up with a ton of conditional DisplayStrings.

```xml
<Type Name="Bar">
  <DisplayString Condition="format==FooFormat::FooFormat_Foo">fmt=Foo</DisplayString>
  <DisplayString Condition="format==FooFormat::FooFormat_Bar">fmt=Bar</DisplayString>
  <DisplayString>fmt={format}</DisplayString>
</Type>
```

Another approach, if you are using C++11 or above, I would go with scoped enums (`enum class FooFormat { Foo, Bar, Baz, COUNT };`). These are a bit better than regular enums and instead of `FooFormat_Foo` you write `FooFormat::Foo`. So you still have the verbose code, but the enum values have a shorter identifier and natvis only displays `Foo`. Of course this only works for C++, not for C.

Answer (score 3):

Use [format specifier `en`](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/debugger/format-specifiers-in-cpp) for this:

```
<AutoVisualizer>
  <Type Name="Bar">
    <DisplayString>fmt={format,en}</DisplayString>
  </Type>
</AutoVisualizer>
```

For example:

```
Bar f;
f.format = FooFormat_Bar;
... // breakpoint here
```

[image]